# Returning value from React child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I am beginner in React so I apologize if this is a basic question. I am trying to build an online Sudoku grid using ReactJS but I am unable to render the digits in the field. I have made two components one being the Sudoku.js which renders the complete sudoku block and other being Node.js which consists of an input field wrapped inside a div. the functionality I want is to change the default  value of the input field (which is "" in my case) whenever the user types a number. I have tried the below approach. It updates the value of my **grid** variable but does not show the updated value in the input field of **Node**. Kindly help.

Sudoku.js

```
const sudokugrid = (
    <div>
        {grid.map((row,rowIdx) => {
            return (
                <div key = {rowIdx} className="rowWrapper">
                    {row.map((col,colIdx) => {
                        var element = grid[rowIdx][colIdx].value;
                        
                        const change = (event) => {
                            element = event.target.value;
                            grid[rowIdx][colIdx].value = element;
                                                      
                            setGrid(grid);
                            return element;
                        }

                        return (
                            <Node
                                key = {colIdx}
                                onChangeValue = {change}
                                value = {element}
                            />
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>
);
```

here **grid** is a 2D array of 9x9 elements which have initial value of all the elements being "" , which are supposed to be updated when the user types in the value in the respective fields. the problem is that the value is updated when the user types the number but the number is not shown in the input field

The Node component is as follows:

```
function Node(props){
return (
    <div className="box">
        <input 
            className = "num" 
            type="number" 
            value = {props.value}
            onChange = {props.onChangeValue}
        />
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because react can't detect mutations. See this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-in-react-ebe55253a1cc/). You have to store the sudoku grid in a state value and change the state with a callback function.
An [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-njidqz?file=src/App.js).
I suggest using an object map for storing the state because you can manage the values a lot easier.

Comment: thank you for the response, but I still have a doubt. I had initialized grid using useState() at the start of the code. In the function **change** I called the **setGrid()** to change the grid  array, so shouldn't it detect mutations?

Comment: No, because the array reference remains the same. And also you use objects in the array, and the object reference also remains the same.